# how to add key value pair to javascript object with key as a variable

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add a key value pair to a javascript object, except the key is a variable representing something else.

See the code for what I've tried

This is my code so far:

```
var temp = 3;
var dictionary = {};

dictionary["temp"] = 4;
console.log(dictionary);
```

When I do `console.log(dictionary)` I am getting `{temp: 4}`, when I actually want `{3:4}`. How should I go about this so that the key added is what temp actually represents. I know I could've just done `dictionary.3 = 4`, but answering this question (using the temp variable) will help me solve a larger, more complex problem.

Comment: change code to this: ```dictionary[temp] = 4; console.log(dictionary);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the variable `"temp"` to dynamic `temp`(get rid of the double quotes).

```js
var temp = 3; 
var dictionary = {};

dictionary[temp] = 4;
console.log(dictionary);
```